# Create write protected file using java

Tags: java, java-io

I want to create a text file using java which is write protected so that no body can make changes to it.

Comment: You can use file.setReadOnly() method. but i think this is not place to write search keyword in question!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [setReadOnly()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadOnly%28%29) method of `File`:

```
File f = new File("/path/to/file");
f.setReadOnly();
```